# Loop through array results within last hour

Tags: php

I have a script that queries an API and finds records within the last day.

I'd like to then loop through these results and solely get those within the last hour.

Can someone explain how I do this?

This is my array of daily results:

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(36) {
    ["CallRef"]=> string(10) "1234567891"
    ["CallStartTime"]=> string(8) "08:18:30"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(36) {
    ["CallRef"]=> string(10) "1234567892"
    ["CallStartTime"]=> string(8) "14:04:20"
  }
}
```

It's 14:40 here in the UK so my script *should* just grab the 2nd item from the array.

Comment: So have you tried anything yourself or are you asking us to write a script for you?

Comment: I was just hoping for a little guidance in creating a `foreach` loop to just find results from the last hour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
$apiElements = [
    ['CallRef' => '1234567891', 'CallStartTime' => '08:18:30'],
    ['CallRef' => '1234567892', 'CallStartTime' => '14:04:20'],
];

$currentFormatted = (new DateTime())->format('H');
$startOfHour = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $currentFormatted . ':00:00');
$endOfHour = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $currentFormatted . ':59:59');

$callsInHour = array_filter($apiElements, function($element) use ($startOfHour, $endOfHour) {
    $dt = DateTime::createFromFormat('H:i:s', $element['CallStartTime']);
    return $dt >= $startOfHour && $dt <= $endOfHour; 
});
```

Totally untested, but give it a try.

Next time, please post what code you tried...

Comment: Thanks for this. Your version works great, but when I swap out `$apiElements` for `$result` (the variable that holds my data) I get the following errors: `Illegal string offset 'CallStartTime'` & `Undefined index: CallStartTime`.

Comment: do you not always get `CallStartTime` from the API?

Comment: check your data and make sure that array always follows the same format; otherwise, you'll have to do some extra checking, like: `isset($element['CallStartTime'])` and handle exceptions properly

Comment: I always get it from the API. That's the odd thing. Is it something to do with my array I get from the API?

Comment: has to be, check what that array contains, and if the format is always the same

Comment: @michaelmcgurk there you go... http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d756361f0365065f1ca4d3f24a7345d4a3ed6361

Comment: Thanks for this. I'm really not sure why it doesn't work with my array :(

Comment: Sure, so as you can see you have a wrapper element called `item`, make sure you do `$element['item']`, otherwise it won't work

Comment: Thanks for your patience with me. When I run `$element['item']` I get the following message: `Illegal string offset 'item'` along with `Illegal string offset 'CallStartTime'` & `Undefined index: CallStartTime`.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133743/discussion-between-magd-kudama-and-michaelmcgurk).

Answer (score 1):

Theres multiple ways to do this. You can get a Unix timestmap from a hour ago: `strtotime('-1 hour')`. You can [explode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) the time on every `:` in the time and take the 2nd result from the explode result.

```
foreach ($array as $value){
    $exploded=explode(":",$value['CallStartTime']);
    if(date('H')-1>$exploded[1]){
       //This means it's an hour ago.
    }
}
```

Comment: Many thanks, Loko - I will try implement this solution right now. Part of me was also considering populating a table in a database and using something like `where date >= DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 1 HOUR); ` to get the data that way :-) Will report back shortly. Thank you.

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Yes please let me know

Comment: When I try this, I get `Warning</b>:  Illegal string offset 'CallStartTime'`

Comment: @michaelmcgurk what if you put an `if(isset($value['CallStartTime'])){` in the foreach?

Comment: Running `if(isset($value['CallStartTime'])){` doesn't return true :( Where do you think my problem now lies?

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Since I saw that you have a problem with someone else his code as well and getting this warning, it probably means you didnt give us your exact code or made a typo or something. Try to `var_dump($value);` in your foreach. What does it return?

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. When I run `var_dump($value)` I get the following output: `array(1) {
  ["item"]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    array(36) {
      ["CallStartTime"]=>
      string(8) "08:18:30"
    }
  }
}`

Comment: @michaelmcgurk Yes that means the array in your question isnt the exact array you have. You need `$value['item'][0]['CallStartTime']`. Can you give some more examples of like the array with at least 3 CallStartTimes

Answer (score 0):

Replace `$allResults` and try this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');
$hourAgo = strtotime(date('H:i:s')) - 3600;
foreach ($allResults as $result){
    if(strtotime($result["CallStartTime"]) > $hourAgo){
        var_dump($result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

More flexible solution:

First you need a function to convert time to seconds

```
function convertTimeToSeconds($hhmmss)
{
    //correct format if needed
    list($hours, $minutes, $seconds) = explode(':', $hhmmss);
    return $hours * 3600 + $minutes * 60 + $seconds;
}
```

And then you just can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function

```
    $now = date('H:i:s');
    $nowSeconds = convertTimeToSeconds($now);
    $filterFunction = function ($value) use ($nowSeconds) {
        return ($nowSeconds - convertTimeToSeconds($value['CallStartTime'])) < 3600; //3600 seconds = hour
    };
    $filteredList = array_filter($array, $filterFunction);
```

All together https://3v4l.org/icAmp

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have this `array`

```
    Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [CallRef] => 1234567892
            [CallStartTime] => 21:04:20
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [CallRef] => 1234567892
            [CallStartTime] => 09:08:08
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [CallRef] => 1234567892
            [CallStartTime] => 08:11:08
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [CallRef] => 1234567892
            [CallStartTime] => 20:59:08
        )

)
```

And so i tried this

```
    <?php

     $arr = array( 
            "0" => array (
               "CallRef" => 1234567892,
               "CallStartTime" => "21:04:20"
            ),

            "1" => array (
                "CallRef" => 1234567892,
               "CallStartTime" => "09:08:08"
            ),
            "2" => array (
                "CallRef" => 1234567892,
               "CallStartTime" => "08:11:08"
            ),
            "3" => array (
                "CallRef" => 1234567892,
               "CallStartTime" => "20:59:08"
            )
         );
         //echo "<pre>";print_r($arr);die;
     date_default_timezone_set('Asia/kolkata');//set your timezone
     $currentTime = date('H:i:s');//getting current time
     $lastHourTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));//getting last hour time
     $result = array();
     foreach ($arr as $singlearr){
         if(strtotime($singlearr['CallStartTime']) >= strtotime($lastHourTime) && strtotime($singlearr['CallStartTime']) <= strtotime($currentTime)){
             $result[] = $singlearr;    
         }else{

         }

}
     echo "<pre>";print_r($result);die;//this gives me last hour records only
```

[Check Demo](https://3v4l.org/FOv4P) When you check demo All records which have `time > last hour`  will return otherwise it will return empty array

May be it can help!

Comment: Many thanks for this. Is this easy to change to be the in the last 24 hours too?

Comment: No you will need `date` also in `CallStartTime` otherwise how will we compare value suppose current time is `12:31:00` and in your `CallStartTime = 12:31:00` but which date here?? ,so that will cause problem.